# firebase download url is not downloading image, audio and video on web

Tags: firebase

i'm new on firebase, i succesfully uploads images, audios and videos on firebase storage but when i access there items via download url, it shows me preview on browser instead of downloading the file. Can anyone tell me whats the issue?

Comment: It's really important you review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Questions like this are unanswerable as we don't know what your code looks like, what your structure is or what troubleshooting you've done. I would suggest deleting this question, reading the guides and then posting a question that gives us enough info to help. Then we can take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research alot i find answer of my question. Hope its help for future visitors.

```
download(url : string, filename: string){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
      a.download = filename; // Name the file anything you'd like.
      a.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
  }
```